# on changing page of Table calendar the Page is getting back to the previous one?

Tags: flutter, dart

**on changing page of Table calendar the Page is getting back to the previous one?

*Meaning if I change the month from June to July it'll get back to June.*


I'm using the onPageChanged function which is called when the page of the calendar changes.**

```
onPageChanged: (date) {
                      eventsMap(date.month, date.year);
                    },
```

**inside of eventsMap() function**

```
Future<void> eventsMap(int m, int y) async {
    selectedEvents = {};
    var eventsList = [];
    eventsList = await getEvents(KEY!, m, y);

    for (int i = 0; i < eventsList.length; i++) {
      var inputFormat = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');
      var date1 = inputFormat.parse(eventsList[i].FullDate);

      var outputFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
      var d = outputFormat.format(date1);
      var date2 = DateTime.parse(d);
      if (selectedEvents.containsKey(date2)) {
        selectedEvents[date2]!.add(Event(eventsList[i].Date,
            eventsList[i].BookingText, eventsList[i].FullDate));
        // print('if' + selectedEvents.toString());
      } else {
        selectedEvents[date2] = [
          Event(eventsList[i].Date, eventsList[i].BookingText,
              eventsList[i].FullDate)
        ];
        // print('else' + selectedEvents.toString());
      }
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
The focusedDay: selectedDay, so I updated it in onPageChanged.
```

```
focusedDay: selectedDay,
                    onPageChanged: (date) {
                      selectedDay = date;
                      eventsMap(date.month, date.year);
                    },
```